# Allowing core thread timeout with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Could you explain me, why in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` javadoc is this:

> Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set `corePoolSize` to
>       zero or use `allowCoreThreadTimeOut` because this may leave the pool without 
>       threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run.

I've tried to analyze how new threads are created in this thread pool when a new task has to be executed and I think problem described in javadoc shouldn't happen.

Comment: What do you mean should not happen?

Comment: When execute method is called, then called is ensurePrestart, which adds worker if worker count is less than core pool size. So, the situation when the task is not executed because there isn't any thread in the thread pool is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread pool trys to make the number of work threads equals `corePoolSize`, to improve efficiency by caching threads. Allowing core thread time out is contrary to this purpose. If you allow core thread time out, new task will be executed, but leads to repeatly create and destroy work threads.

If you set `allowCoreThreadTimeOut = true`, then after the work thread find no task in task queue and time out, they will be destroyed even the number of working threads is less than `corePoolSize`. So, if you submit new task at this time, the thread pool has to create new thread.

If you set `allowCoreThreadTimeOut = false`, then after the work thread find no task in task queue and number of work threads less than `corePoolSize`, they will be not be destroyed and keep waiting for new task.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the answer is stale Javadoc, for the most part. As you note, `ensurePrestart` ensures that as long as `corePoolSize` > 0, the number of core pool threads is nonzero after the call. This has been the case since https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/2d19ea519b17529a083a62eb219da532693bbef3, but notably that commit did not update the Javadoc on `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

However, the details aren't quite so simple either. Rather than only worrying about new task submissions and task reschedule on completion, you also need to worry about core pool threads idling out because all scheduled tasks are too far in the future to trigger before the pool timeout.

Not sure if I'm reading the JRE code correctly, but it looks like in such a case, the pool will:

1. Start a worker thread (due to `ensurePrestart`)
2. Regardless of thread type (core or not), the thread is eligible for timeout because `allowCoreThreadTimeout` is true
3. Worker thread polls `DelayedWorkQueue` for next task, with timeout
4. poll returns `null` (times out), because the next scheduled task is beyond pool timeout
5. The core thread will terminate because it thinks there is nothing to do
6. `ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit` will run on worker termination. It will check the queue, notice that it's nonempty, and thus require a minimum of at least one thread
7. If the thread being terminated is the last thread, it will notice that the minimum is not met and immediately start a new (non-core) worker
8. Repeat from step 1

So, the pool *will* work as you intend, but probably won't be in an ideal state either (you really want a single core thread polling without timeout here, not threads constantly spinning up, polling with timeout, timing out, then starting a new thread to replace itself). In that sense, step 6 is really what prevents the case mentioned in Javadoc (by the time tasks are eligible, all pool threads have timed out), but it does so imperfectly because of the unnecessary thread creation/destruction loop.

This weirdness is really because `DelayedWorkQueue` semantically breaks the `BlockingQueue` contract. All else equal, you'd assume that `size() > 0` implies that a subsequent `poll(...)` will successfully retrieve an element and not time out, but `DelayedWorkQueue` allows those elements to be held back for some time (even though they're already visible via `size()` and `isEmpty()`).

NOTE: Seems like this code changed in Java 8, with the addition of [this condition](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/4fd805da91373f38ad42b83040b99c7f1885cb4f#diff-03b58785a5fb4b1a2b29f21eea5a8a106de621e8467446a8d48888551c168618R1058) to `ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask()`. This will keep that last worker thread alive and avoid the thread create/destroy loop, but it will busy-poll the work queue for work instead.